# Can Tomcat be configured as the proxy for apache?

Tags: apache, perl, tomcat, proxy, single-sign-on

I have inherited a Perl/MySQL application running on xampp Apache.  I have been tasked with adding SSO, and the implementation being made available to me requires Tomcat. I have installed the Tomcat module from the most recent xampp, so that leaves me with Apache 2.4 and Tomcat 7.0.

I have encountered several similar questions here on StackOverflow that address setting up Apache as the proxy server for Tomcat, but isn't that backward from what I need?  My brain is getting stuck on that concept.  I envision a request coming to the server, Tomcat intercepts it first and performs authentication with my SSO app, and then forwards the request to Apache where the original request is served.

I know that Tomcat would be able to handle (serve) the Perl application, but I cringe at the thought of reconfiguring the existing Apache setup to move the app to Tomcat.  Unless someone can provide a simple, 3-step process for doing so....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen that scenario ever. And due to the standard mode of operation it doesn't make much sense: Apache httpd easily covers ports 80 and 443, while tomcat needs to jump through a lot of hoops (typically being proxied by a proper webserver)

For SSO, you don't necessarily need to intercept a request - you can also go with cookies or initial redirects (e.g. an unauthenticated request gets redirected to the SSO address, then bounced back to (e.g.) a well known URL, with some cryptographically signed identity information)

As you're not mentioning if you have a homegrown or an industry standard SSO system, it's hard to recommend what you should do. However, I'd definitely stay away from configuring tomcat as a Proxy to Apache httpd. Sounds completely backwards to me.